# Rust struct type aliases and "inheriting" methods

Tags: rust

#### First Question

---

Say I have the following struct:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Vec3 {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64,
}

impl Vec3 {
    pub fn dot(self, v: Vec3) -> f64 { ... }
    pub fn add(self, v: Vec3) -> Vec3 { ... }
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to differentiate the use of `Vec3` as either `Point`, representing a point in 3D space, and `Color`, representing an RGB value. A first step would be to use type aliases:

```rust
pub type Point = Vec3;
pub type Color = Vec3;
```

Then in the rest of my code, I would use the type annotations `Point` and `Color` to suggest what a variable is suppose to be. However, it's only a suggestion. Nothing is stopping me from inputing a `Color` as an argument that is type hinted as `Point` (since at the end of the day, they are really just `Vec3`).

**First question:** Is there a way to force the rust compiler to treat `Point` and `Color` as different types?

#### Second Question

---

Say I wanted to implement certain methods that can only be used on a `Point` and then another set of methods that can only be used on `Color`, for example:

```rust
impl Point {
    fn point_on_line(&self, t: f64) -> Point { ... }
    ...
}

impl Color {
    fn to_hex(self) -> String { ... }
    ...
}
```

Of course, I still want instances of `Color` and `Point` to retain the methods in `Vec3`.

The simplest way I can think of doing such would be to convert `Vec3` to a trait and then make `Point` and `Color` struct implementations for `Vec3`:

```rust
pub trait Vec3: Copy + Clone + Debug {
    fn dot(self, v: Vec3) -> f64 { ... }
    fn add(self, v: Vec3) -> Vec3 { ... }
    ...

    // now requires the definition of .x(), .y(), and .z() in order
    // to create default implementations for the above methods
    fn x(self) -> f64;
    fn y(self) -> f64;
    fn z(self) -> f64;
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}

impl Vec3 for Point {
    fn x(self) -> f64 { self.x }
    fn y(self) -> f64 { self.y }
    fn z(self) -> f64 { self.z }
}
```

Of course, this would require the trait to use `.x()` in place of `.x` everywhere in the default implementations.

**Second question:** Is there a "cleaner" or more idiomatic approach to get the above desired behaviour? If not, is there any overhead incurred by the extra copy via the `.x(), .y(), .z()` methods (since we are copying the value through an additional method)? I'm assuming the answer to the latter question is no, in that the compiler will optimize that away, but this is for a performance critical application so I'm just wondering about the exact details of that.

Comment: If you need stricter type checking, the usual way is a light wrapper: `struct Color(Vec3)` which has `impl Deref<Vec3>`. I can see how "color" is a special case, but is `Point` necessarily different?

Comment: In practice, yeah, Point and Vec3 are very much the same (in fact, things like dot and cross should probably be under Point since they are not necessarily relevant for `Color`, but that's a design decision). I guess the question is more about the general case. @tadman Are there any performance concerns when using `impl Deref`?

Comment: As far as I know Rust is really good about that implementation detail boiling away to nothing in the optimization pass, but do be sure to benchmark if this is important to your use case. `Deref` is used by all kinds of things that are used in "hot" code, like `Box` or `Arc` and it seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite rust trick is to use generic to have different specialization of one structure:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Vec3<Behavior> {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64,
    behavior: Behavior,
}

pub struct Color;
pub struct Point;

/// not neeeded but help for documentation
trait Vec3Behavior {}
impl Vec3Behavior for Color {}
impl Vec3Behavior for Point {}

impl<Behavior> Vec3<Behavior> {
    pub fn point(x: f64, y: f64, z: f64) -> Vec3<Point> {
        Vec3 {
            x,
            y,
            z,
            behavior: Point,
        }
    }

    pub fn color(x: f64, y: f64, z: f64) -> Vec3<Color> {
        Vec3 {
            x,
            y,
            z,
            behavior: Color,
        }
    }

    pub fn dot(self, v: Self) -> f64 {
        todo!()
    }
    pub fn add(self, v: Self) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Vec3<Point> {
    fn point_on_line(&self, t: f64) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Vec3<Color> {
    fn to_hex(&self) -> String {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Thus I don't know if your use case make much sense but anyway.

Comment: This is what I was going to say. Except I would call the marker structs something else, and then have `pub type Point = Vec3<PointBehavior>` or similar. And I would move the constructors to their respective impls and call them `new`, so they can be called as `Point::new` and `Color::new`.

Comment: @drewtato yes that also could be a thing matter of taste

Comment: Also you'd need to derive `Clone, Copy, Debug` for the marker structs, otherwise the derives will do nothing. If you make `Vec3Behavior` a subtrait of the derived traits, then this will at least be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to force the rust compiler to treat Point and Color as different types?

No. The usual way to do this is with a newtype/wrapper type.

```rs
pub struct Color(pub Vec3);
pub struct Point(pub Vec3);
```

If you want to use a trait, you can have one method that returns a `Vec3` and have the rest have default implementations that call that method. This lessens the amount of duplicate code.

```rs
pub trait Vec3Trait {
    fn vec3(self) -> Vec3;
    fn x(self) -> f64 {
        self.vec3().x
    }
    fn y(self) -> f64 {
        self.vec3().y
    }
    fn z(self) -> f64 {
        self.vec3().z
    }
}
```

I would say this is the idiomatic way. The `Vec3<Behavior>` answer describes another way that should be just as good, although I wouldn't say it's idiomatic since the documentation doesn't end up as nice.

> If not, is there any overhead incurred by the extra copy via the `.x(), .y(), .z()` methods

Since this kind of getter method is used extensively, it's very likely to be optimized. Even if these are inlined, it might cause something else to not be inlined, reducing speed. As always, you would need to benchmark your full application on real data to know if it has any effect.